# why would ffmpeg rotate 2nd video on concatenation when I don't want it to or seemingly ask for it?

Tags: ffmpeg

here is the command I run:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -an -i ./files.txt ztestout.mp4
```

I have about 5 videos, but just to test I did with two.
the 2nd video gets flipped upside down, even though opening each video in VLC opens and plays them correctly.

Any ideas why it would do that?  Is the metadata wrong in the video?  I took all the videos I'm trying to concat with the same android phone.

output below, and I noticed its says rotation zero degrees:

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x138804730] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from './files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17255 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m, progressive), 1920x1080, 16999 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-01-08T13:32:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-01-08T13:32:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'ztestout.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-01-08T13:32:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x138904b40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filterdrop=20 speed=3.67x    
frame=74497 fps=109 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1740353kB time=00:41:23.13 bitrate=5741.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=25 speed=3.64x    
video:1739531kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.047236%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] frame I:300   Avg QP:20.73  size:294110
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] frame P:29265 Avg QP:23.65  size: 45500
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] frame B:44932 Avg QP:27.95  size:  8045
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] consecutive B-frames: 19.4%  0.4%  0.7% 79.5%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] mb I  I16..4:  5.5% 43.8% 50.7%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.9%  0.7%  P16..4: 36.9% 13.9% 10.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:36.6%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.1%  B16..8: 30.0%  3.0%  1.3%  direct: 1.1%  skip:64.3%  L0:38.1% L1:55.8% BI: 6.1%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] 8x8 transform intra:49.7% inter:45.0%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 84.0% 82.3% 41.9% inter: 12.8% 10.8% 0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 30% 17%  8% 45%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 25% 12%  4%  7%  7% 12%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 25% 12%  5%  7%  7% 10%  6%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 22% 22%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.3% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] ref P L0: 70.3% 10.7% 13.9%  5.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] ref B L0: 91.8%  6.2%  2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] ref B L1: 95.7%  4.3%
[libx264 @ 0x137f07fe0] kb/s:5738.58
```

Comment: It also says `displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees` i.e. upside down